# Mathematica 12, supported GPUs

Tags: cudalink, version-12

It seems that Mathematica 12 doesn't support NVidia 2xxx (i.e 2080), 16xx or 1xxx series. Could it be that the CUDA section has not yet been rewritten for 12?

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/tutorial/Reference.html#522022378

Comment: Mathematica 10 appears to have the same documentation included, but CUDALink seems to work fine on the 10xx series GPU I have in my machine. It's likely just not been updated yet.

Comment: Looks like Mathematica 11.x has CUDA 9.1 support, which includes pascal and volta chips; but not turing (20x0, 1660 notably). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA No info whereas 12 supports 20x0 series yet.

Comment: Yes, version 12 does support Turing GPUs.

Comment: @illian: Mathematica 12 supports turing GPUs from NVidia, does this mean it supports e.g. RTX 2080 ti. Is there somewhere a list which GPUs are supported by Mathematica 12?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/81244)

Comment: @Wolfgang123 you can find some relevant information in my answer :D but to address your query directly: Yes, but you are better to do something like Niki's command recommendations to perform a direct check.

Comment: @JeromeIbanes did you find my answer to be sufficient? If I can provide more clarity, please let me know. Otherwise, would you be kind enough to accept my answer to your question? :D I hope this is not too crooked of a request!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Tl;dr [Version 12 supports CUDA 10.1, which includes support for Turing Architecture.](http://www.wolfram.com/CUDA/CUDAResources.html)

To download the most updated version, even if you’ve just updated & are having trouble:

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
CUDAResourcesInstall["<path_to_paclet>", Update->True]
```

As noted by @ilian, version 12 supports Turing chips/architecture. What this means is that GPUs with these chips will be supported. Turing chips are in all RTX cards. You only gain more and more access to computing resources as you go from 2060->2080. 2080->2080 Ti brings you a "true" Turing chip, with the RTX Titan having a "fully unlocked" Turing chip. All of these use Cuda 10, which is what is supported by Version 12 of Wolfram Language and Mathematica.

I will not discuss the [Nvidia GPU Turing Architectures](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/turing/) further, as that is outside of the scope of this forum. However, please see [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1486844) for the source of this concrete commented notation of this compatibility:

*"Neural nets in Mathematica 12 will use CUDA 10 and be compatible with your GPU."*

-Sebastian Bodenstein, Wolfram Research

Comment: that "Nvidia GPU Turing Architecture" link is about GeForce cards (GTX/RTX). You can't assume it works for other product lines, such as Tesla or Quadro. It says "GeForce" in the URL, and things are quite a bit different for Tesla cards, for example.

Comment: @AndreasLauschke precisely! This is a valid point, which is why I do not mention it here. Only Turing architecture is discussed.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. It's fine not to discuss Turing. What I meant is that it's contradictory to say "won't discuss Turing", but then give a link that's Turing only on GeForce. A better link would for example be https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/design-visualization/technologies/turing-architecture/

Comment: and if M12 supports CUDA 10.1, why does Import@FileNameJoin[{$CUDALinkPath, "version.txt"}] return 8.0.61 then?

Comment: I meant that I would not discuss the structure of their architecture. Turing chips are what are present in the cards. I think your second ask for clarification is the version of CUDALink that you have.

Comment: a), right, so don't just use a link that's only about Turing in GeForce :) b) that can't be the "version of CUDALink". b1: the paclet is called CUDALink-12.0.0. b2: $CUDAResourcesVersion returns 12.0.346. b3: the version number inside CUDALink.m is 8.0 (from 2010) b4: 8.0.61 sounds like a CUDA version I've worked with before, I don't think that's a CUDALink version.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your point is here, but a) is related to the context of this question & answer and b) seems to be in contradiction with the quote from Sebastian.

Comment: a), right, and you simply have that wrong :) b), no, I disagree with*you*, it's your sentence "I think your second ask for clarification is the version of CUDALink that you have" that is wrong. This is my last post on this, I already get the message "Please avoid extended discussions in comments". I think you just don't want to admit you misunderstood everything I wrote, and I leave it at that. I've documented my opinion, that's all I needed here. Bye.

Comment: It is not wrong, as it is according to the context of this question. That is all. Your points are not invalid, they just do not apply here, and seemingly have no origin. I do not discuss those types of cards in this answer, nor are they asked about in the question. As for b, again, I refer to the quote from the lead designer of the tools. Perhaps you may wish to ask a new question, or submit an answer of your own? I cannot offer you more.

Answer (score 1):

Cuda seems to work on Mathematica 12 on a Windows 10 machine:

```
CUDAQ[]
```

> True

```
CUDAInformation[]
```

> {1 -> {"Name" -> "GeForce RTX 2080", "Clock Rate" -> 1710000, 
>      "Compute Capabilities" -> 7.5, "GPU Overlap" -> 1, 
>      "Maximum Block Dimensions" -> {1024, 1024, 64}, 
>      "Maximum Grid Dimensions" -> {2147483647, 65535, 65535}, 
>      "Maximum Threads Per Block" -> 1024, 
>      "Maximum Shared Memory Per Block" -> 49152, 
>      "Total Constant Memory" -> 65536, "Warp Size" -> 32, 
>      "Maximum Pitch" -> 2147483647, 
>      "Maximum Registers Per Block" -> 65536, "Texture Alignment" -> 512,
>       "Multiprocessor Count" -> 46, "Core Count" -> 1472, 
>      "Execution Timeout" -> 1, "Integrated" -> False, 
>      "Can Map Host Memory" -> True, "Compute Mode" -> "Default", 
>      "Texture1D Width" -> 131072, "Texture2D Width" -> 131072, 
>      "Texture2D Height" -> 65536, "Texture3D Width" -> 16384, 
>      "Texture3D Height" -> 16384, "Texture3D Depth" -> 16384, 
>      "Texture2D Array Width" -> 32768, 
>      "Texture2D Array Height" -> 32768, 
>      "Texture2D Array Slices" -> 2048, "Surface Alignment" -> 512, 
>      "Concurrent Kernels" -> True, "ECC Enabled" -> False, 
>      "TCC Enabled" -> False, "Total Memory" -> 8589934592}}

I've also tried `CUDAFourier` and `NetTrain`, both seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced CUDAToolkit 10.1 with 10.0.  The fallback fixed my problems with "GPU not found". (Windows 10 home, Mathematica 12.0)

Comment: See my updated answer, you should be good with 10.1, unless there is something awry with your hardware. After performing the update call I just added and referred to, do you still have issues?